# NG-repeat not working when iterating through JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried, and tried, and tried. I cannot get this right. I took a very basic course CodeSchool as I was very interested in Angular. Although I cannot get this darn ng-repeat to work. -- *Your help is greatly appreciated!*

---

```
    'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('MatchListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log('Attempting API Call');

        $scope.matches = [];

        $http.get("matches.json")
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log('Grabbed matches.json successfully!');
                //Loop through each item and put it onto the matches var
                angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
                    $scope.matches.push(item);
                });

                console.log('Total of ' + $scope.matches.length + ' matches in the array.');
            })

        $scope.theMatches = function ($scope) {
            return $scope.matches;
        }

    }]
);
```

---

And here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MatchListCtrl as matchCtrl">
<p style="font-weight:bold;">{{matchCtrl.getMatches().length}} - Items in the array.</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in matchCtrl.theMatches">{{x.when}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `x in matchCtrl.theMatches()`

Comment: you are mixing syntaxes here.  you are using **both** `$scope` syntax and `ControllerAs` syntax at the same time.  I'll try to work up an answer that corrects this and sticks to one syntax; give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your snippet and modified it, to change it completely to the ControllerAs syntax.  Your initial code was mixing styles, and had some redundancies that can be removed.

When using the ControllerAs syntax, a common pattern is to create a variable to alias the controller first, to be able to access from inside callback functions.  To make it extremely clear what is going on here, I named this variable the same as the alias in the HTML.

Also note, the reference to `$scope` is completely removed here, as is the redundant function `theMatches`.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MatchListCtrl', ['$http',
  function($http) {

    var matchCtrl = this; //consistent reference to controller object

    console.log('Attempting API Call');

    matchCtrl.matches = [];

    $http.get("matches.json")
      .success(function(response) {
        console.log('Grabbed matches.json successfully!');
        angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
          matchCtrl.matches.push(item);
        });

        console.log('Total of ' + matchCtrl.matches.length + ' matches in the array.');
      })
  }
]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MatchListCtrl as matchCtrl">
  <p style="font-weight:bold;">{{matchCtrl.matches.length}} - Items in the array.</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in matchCtrl.matches">{{x.when}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir, are genius! Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there. You just need to tweak it slightly. As `theMatches` has been declared as a function it needs to be invoked as one;

```
<li ng-repeat="x in matchCtrl.theMatches()"> {{ x.when }} </li>
```

I've put together the following plunkr that is a small example of something similar running [plnkr.co/edit/zF8...](http://plnkr.co/edit/zF8EkT32L15EQKCLQrhM).

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.matches = function () {
    return [
      {
        name: 'Bob'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ted'
      }
    ];
  }
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in main.matches()"> {{ x.name }} </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Be aware though that as `matches` is already declared in the scope you can bind your `ng-repeat` to that instead leaving the function redundant.

Any `$http` requests should ideally be refactored into services which can be invoked from within your controller instances. As the request is made when the controller is instantiated it may be worth considering using the router `resolve` option to resolve the data and take the promise logic out of the controller.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Try changing `matchCtrl.theMatches` to `matchCtrl.matches`? Do you have any errors in the console? Also if you are using `controllerAs` you may wish to consider implementing your controller logic in a style that is mindful of this instead of attaching to `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a seperate function to access `$scope.matches`.
angularjs automatically detects the changes on `$scope` properties.

and you need to assign theMatches function to the controller in order to call it as a controller's property, not scope's.

```
this.theMatches = function ($scope) {
    return $scope.matches;
}
```

and after that you need to call the function,

`ng-repeat="x in matchCtrl.theMatches()"`

but as I said, you can just type;

`ng-repeat="x in matches"`

since angularjs automatically has two-ways-data binding on `$scope`.

or if you still want to access as controller's property,

you can simply replace `$scope.matches = [];` with `this.matches = [];`

and type `ng-repeat="x in matchCtrl.matches"`